# Skip insert on duplicate entry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a favorite table containing some fields like login_id,driver_id(One login_id may have many driver_id) . Then I am using bulk update , not having any check the driver_id is exists in table .

Input data will be set of driver ids , I need to skip the insertion of driver id  if the same id  already be there for relevant login_id . So the new ids will be inserted and others are not

What can I do with mysql , what are all the settings needed in table .

Please advise me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use  "INSERT IGNORE INTO".it's return updated row count.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO favorite(login_id,driver_id) VALUES (login_id,driver_id) (login_id,driver_id).....
```

Answer (score 4):

create a unique key with login_id and driver_id in mysql.

When you try to insert an existing record based on those keys, an error will be thrown. You can then trap this error and proceed as normal.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique
  ON tbl_name (login_id, driver_id)
```