# Fast delete duplicate records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

I'm trying to import very big SQL dump (around 37 million rows) into InnoDB table. There are tons of duplicates and what I want to achieve is, without changing actual dump want to prevent duplicate row insertion. The field `email` might have duplicates. I tried following: after importing whole dump into db I tried to execute following SQL:

```
set session old_alter_table=1;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE sample ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

But second query worked around 1 hour and then I just canceled this query.

What is proper way to get rid off duplicates?

I have couple of ideas:

- Maybe before starting to import to make a table with unique index and while insertion to prevent duplicates without harming whole process?
- Maybe after importing dump to select distinct email and to insert into another table?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485674/how-to-skip-duplicate-records-when-importing-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

**From a .dump file**

When importing, use `-f` for "force":

```
mysql -f -p < 2015-10-01.sql
```

This causes the import to continue after an error is encountered, which is useful in this case if you create the unique key constraint before importing.

---

**From a .csv file**

If you are using "LOAD DATA", use "IGNORE", e.g.:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'somefile.csv' IGNORE
    INTO TABLE some_db.some_tbl
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
               OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (`somefield1`,`somefield2`);
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify IGNORE, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique
> key value are discarded.

This requires you to create the unique key constraint before importing, which will be fast on an empty table.

Comment: I have .dump file which consists of sql create table and insert commands. I'm just importing like `mysql -u root -p sample_db < sample_table.dump` It's very hard to edit 1.4 GB text file using VIM in Linux. That's why looking for other solutions which is after importing or which doesn't goes through editing this big file.

Comment: what has `force` to do with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the dump file as follows:

1. Modify the `CREATE TABLE` statement to add a unique key on the `email` field, or add an `ALTER TABLE` statement after it.
2. Find all the `INSERT INTO sample` statements, and change them to `INSERT IGNORE INTO sample`.

You could also do step 2 using a pipeline:

```
sed 's/INSERT INTO sample/INSERT IGNORE INTO sample/' sample_table.dump | mysql -u root -p sample_db
```

If the file is too big to edit to add the `ALTER TABLE` statement, I suggest you create the dump with the `--no-create-info` option to `mysqldump`, and create the table by hand (with the unique key) before loading the dump file.

Comment: 1.5 GB text file. how to replace all occurences?:)

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do this without editing the dump file.